# get last modified for a file that has been unzipped LastWriteTime gives unzip time

Tags: c#, ssis, fileinfo

I am trying to get the last modified date on a file in a SSIS Script task using C#.  the file was in a zip file and has been unzipped.

the following all return the same date (the date of unzipping the file)
File.GetLastWriteTime("File")
File.GetCreationTime("File")

FileInfo.CreationTime;
FileInfo.LastWriteTime;

I know the correct time is somewhere because windows shows the modified time I am looking for.  is there a way to access the attribute that fileExplorer is using?
Thank you
KevCri

Comment: Please include code as well. FileInfo.LastWriteTime should fetch you the last modified date.

Comment: Try `FileInfo.LastAccessTime`